# XSLT Apply templates Not on Same Line

Tags: xslt

I have a pretty basic question today.  Why won't the attributes from all the elements line up?

My desired output is 
"Last_Name","First_Name", "DOB" (if Bene_DOB does not exists then use DOB_DEP)
Like this:
"Gibson","Mel","1965-01-01"
"Norris","Chuck"

> But I am getting:

"Norris","Gibson","Chuck","Mel",

1965-01-01
  12345-01

1965-01-01
  12345-01

I have this XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/BCBSLA_CR_OFAC_BENE">
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:BENE_ALL>
  <wd:Last_Name>Norris</wd:Last_Name>
  <wd:First_Name>Chuck</wd:First_Name>
  <wd:REF_ID>12345-01</wd:REF_ID>
</wd:BENE_ALL>      
  <wd:Last_Name>Gibson</wd:Last_Name>
  <wd:First_Name>Mel</wd:First_Name>
  <wd:REF_ID>12345-02</wd:REF_ID>
</wd:BENE_ALL>
<wd:BENE_PEOPLE>
  <wd:BENE_DOB>1965-01-02</wd:BENE_DOB>
  <wd:Ben_Ref_ID>12345-01</wd:Ben_Ref_ID>
</wd:BENE_PEOPLE>
<wd:BENE_PEOPLE>
  <wd:BENE_DOB>1955-01-10</wd:BENE_DOB>
  <wd:Ben_Ref_ID>12345-02</wd:Ben_Ref_ID>
</wd:BENE_PEOPLE>
<wd:DEP>
  <wd:DOB_Dep>1965-01-01</wd:DOB_Dep>   
  <wd:Dep_Ref_ID>12345-01</wd:Dep_Ref_ID>
</wd:DEP>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

Here's my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
                xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/BCBSLA_CR_OFAC_BENE"
                version="2.0">


  <xsl:output method="text"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wd:BENE_ALL">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:EMPLID" mode="csv"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Last_Name" mode="csv"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:First_Name" mode="csv"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="wd:BENE_People">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:DOB_Bene" mode="csv" />
  </xsl:template>


  <!--<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=
    </xsl:choose>-->


  <xsl:template match="*" mode="csv">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;,')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="csv-nl">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;&#xA;')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you post an example with more than one `wd:BENE_DOB` and `wd:DOB_Dep`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the structure of your XML, you need to create a new data row for each group of elements starting with `Last_Name`. In XSLT 2.0, this could be accomplished by doing:

```
<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry/BENE_ALL/*" group-starting-with="Last_Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;,')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', current-group()[self::First_Name], '&quot;&#10;')" />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

returning:

```
"Norris","Chuck"
"Gibson","Mel"
```

---

To add the `Bene_DOB` value, you could use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) like this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/BCBSLA_CR_OFAC_BENE">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="person-dob" match="BENE_DOB" use="following-sibling::Ben_Ref_ID[1]" />

<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry/BENE_ALL/*" group-starting-with="Last_Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;,')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', current-group()[self::First_Name], '&quot;,')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', key('person-dob', current-group()[self::REF_ID]), '&quot;&#10;')" />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/naZXpX2

This is assuming the keys are listed in pairs of `BENE_DOB`, `Ben_Ref_ID`.

---

If you like, you could reduce code repetition by defining a function as:

```
<xsl:function name="my:quote">
    <xsl:param name="text"/> 
    <xsl:sequence select="concat('&quot;', $text, '&quot;')" />
</xsl:function>
```

and then:

```
<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry/BENE_ALL/*" group-starting-with="Last_Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="my:quote(.), my:quote(current-group()[self::First_Name]), my:quote(key('person-dob', current-group()[self::REF_ID]))" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/naZXpX2/1

Comment: Thanks Michael - I've rewritten it using value-of, and that has solved my problem of items not appearing on a single line.  Thanks!  The key isn't working for me though because I have XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @BWatkins Your original stylesheet is tagged as `version="2.0"`, so I assumed that's what your processor supports. In any case, the key does work in XSLT 1.0, but `xsl:for-each-group` does not. Judging from your updated XML, you don't need it.